# Change publish method for azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to change the publish method for an azure function without deleting and recreating it? Currently I want to swap the publish method from code to docker containers for a couple of azure functions apps.

I am not able to find anything useful for this matter under the deployment center or under the Microsoft's Azure CLI documentation.

I've seen that it's possible to do that for webapps but didn't found much about azure functions apps.

I highly appreciate any kind of help!
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the suitable MS [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process,powershell,azure-cli&pivots=programming-language-csharp) for your requirement of changing the Publish Method of Azure Functions to the Docker Container.

This documentation contains different ways of achieving the above requirement such as using the Azure Functions core tools commands, CLI and also PowerShell Commands.

The actual way of deploying/publishing the Azure Functions is creating the Azure functions along with the docker image initialization. But, when publishing the Azure Functions code manually to docker, you need the docker file in your Azure Functions Project.

You can initialize the docker file using the command `func init --worker-runtime -docker` which will prompts for the langauge runtime such as Java, dotnet, node, python, etc.

Refer to the [*SoundCode*](https://markheath.net/post/azure-functions-docker) article given by @*MarkHeath* and [*Educba*](https://www.educba.com/azure-functions-docker/) article for more information on adding the docker file in Azure Functions project and publishing to docker.

Comment: Is it possible to change the publish method for an azure function without deleting and recreating it?